# Using Javascript and PHP variables to update data on page

Tags: javascript, php

all,

I can't get something working right that I'm sure you could help out with.  I have a page that displays documents linked to a database entry, and the user can either remove docs, or add new ones.  When docs are removed, the table displaying them is updated automatically and the row removed, a php script called, and that DB entry removed as well.  This is working fine.

What I need help with is populating a new row in the table dynamically once the user adds a new doc.  I have a script that adds the doc record to the DB, and I can use PHP to get the newly assigned DocID (primary key in DB that is auto increment), but how do I push that doc ID back to javascript so it can update the table with the doc id.

How do I pass the docid from the php script to cell2 in the javascript?

See some code examples below.

HTML:

```
<div id="quoteleft">
          List of linked docs here, with option to delete them.
          <span id="removelink"></span>
          <INPUT type="button" class="button-delrow" onClick="deleteLink('linkTable')" />
            <table id="linkTable" width="95%" border="1" align="center">
              <tr><th></th><th>ID</th><th>Link to Doc</th><th>Description</th></tr>

               <?php $c = 0;
               while(!$GetDocInfo->atEnd()) { 
                 $c++;  ?>
                <tr><td><INPUT type="checkbox" id="chkbox1" name="chkbox[]"/></td>
                  <td><?php echo($GetDocInfo->getColumnVal("docid")); ?></td>
                  <td><a href="file:///C|/Users/Chad/Desktop/<?php echo($GetDocInfo->getColumnVal("filename")); ?>">C:/Users/Chad/Desktop/<?php echo($GetDocInfo->getColumnVal("filename")); ?></a></td>
                  <td><?php echo($GetDocInfo->getColumnVal("description")); ?></td>
                </tr>
              <?php $GetDocInfo->moveNext(); } $GetDocInfo->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record ?>

            </table>

          </div> <!-- end quote left -->
          <div id="quoteright">
          Select new files to link here. <br>
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br>
            Description: <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc"><br>
            <input type="button" value="Link" name="lnk" onClick="doclink(fileToUpload.value, <?php echo($GetPartInfo->getColumnVal("rfqid")); ?>, desc.value)"><br>
            <span id="link"></span>
          </div> <!-- end quote right -->
```

Javascript:

```
function doclink(doc, rfqid, desc) {
      document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = '<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />';
      text = "docname="+doc+"&rfqid="+rfqid+"&desc="+desc;
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("POST","./link.php",true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("link").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        //document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = doc;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.send(text);

      var table = document.getElementById('linkTable');

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        // Add delete row button
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name="chkbox[]";
        element1.id="checkbox"+(rowCount+1);
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        //Add docid to doc
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = "ID";

        //Add link to doc
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell3.innerHTML = "<a href='file:///C|/Users/Chad/Desktop/"+doc+"'>C:/Users/Chad/Desktop/"+doc+"></a>";

        //Add description
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell4.innerHTML = desc;


} //end function link
```

PHP script:

```
  $insert = "insert into doc (rfqid, filename, description) values ('$rfqid', '$file', '$desc')";
  echo "<br>Insert: $insert <br>";
  $err = mysqli_query($CSCRFQ, $insert);
    if ($err === false ) {
        echo "ERROR <br>";
    }

$GetDocID = new WA_MySQLi_RS("GetDocID",$CSCRFQ,1);
$GetDocID->setQuery("SELECT max(docid) FROM doc WHERE rfqid=?");
$GetDocID->bindParam("i", "".$rfqid  ."", "-1"); //colname
$GetDocID->execute();
 //global $docid;
 $docid = $GetDocID->getColumnVal("max(docid)");

  echo "<br>FILE: $file <br>";
```

Comment: Do it as an AJAX call?

Comment: Seems to me you already know how to do it. Just have your existing PHP script do the extra work before sending a response back to the JavaScript (which it is doing when it finishes, regardless of if you actually send any content back).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, I got it working by modifying my javascript to the following.

```
function doclink(doc, rfqid, desc) {
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "link.php",
          data: "docname="+doc+"&rfqid="+rfqid+"&desc="+desc,
          dataType:'json', //or HTML, JSON, etc.
          success: function(response){
              alert(response);

              var docid = response[0];
              var file = response[1];

      // do more stuff

}
});
}
```

and my php script to echo/return an array:

```
 $answer = array();
 $answer[0] = $docid;
 $answer[1] = $file;

  echo json_encode($answer);
  exit;
```

Thanks,
Chad